# map inserting key values into wrong key?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have been having this problem for awhile with my code, looking for my mistake I can't see it.  I have a map, map I am mapping keywords to the values.
My problem is sometimes when inserting keyword = "Blue" the value is inserting into the Key for "Red".
So instead of,
Key: Red, Value: obj1, obj2
Key: Blue, Value: obj3, obj4
I get,
Key: Red, Value: obj1, obj2, obj4 (obj4 should be keyed to Blue)
Key: Blue, Value: obj3

Not sure what it can be since the same version of the code works for other maps that I have, they just don't have as many Keys.

```
addKeywordsForObject(const Object* const object, int nKeywords, ...)
{
va_list     keywords;
char        *keyword;

va_start(keywords, nKeywords);
for (int i = 0; i < nKeywords; i++) {
    keyword = va_arg(keywords, char*);

    if(objectToKeywordMap.find(keyword) == objectToKeywordMap.end()) {  
        keywordObject = new ObjectSet();
        keywordObject->insert(const_cast<Object* const>(object));
        objectToKeywordMap.emplace(StringToObjectSetMap::value_type(keyword,keywordObject));
    }
    else {
        keywordObject->insert(const_cast<Object* const>(object));   
        objectToKeywordMap.emplace(StringToObjectSetMap::value_type(keyword,keywordObject));
    }
}
va_end(keywords);
}
```

Comment: Show where do these char* pointers come from, how do you create them? Looks like you're not aware that keys in the map are pointers, not strings, and the map does not compare them like strings.

Comment: You don't show how the keys are stored in the map. There would be a big difference between `std::string` and `char*`! A common problem is comparing the pointers and not the string values.

Comment: Guess I left that out. The keys are stored as strings. the map is map<string, ObjectSet*>.  I had tried using a tempString to store the char* keyword as a string before using it in the map, but it didn't have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no declaration for `keywordObject`, so I shall assume it's a global. The case of adding a new object to a keyword which is already present  is dealt with in the `else`. What is the value of `keywordObject` in this case? Who sets it?

There are a number of other problems with this code, some mentioned in other answers and comments.

- missing return type for `addKeywordsForObject`
- possible usage of `char*` as a map key which requires special handling (not clear, because you haven't shown the declaration of `StringToObjectSetMap`)
- a function which takes a variable number of parameters by using ellipsis (almost never a good idea in C++)
- use of a global variable where a local variable is appropriate

Comment: no return type, it is a void function.  map key is string, map<string, ObjectSet*>  program is a port from java which used varargs as the keywords so that is why this is taking variable parameters

Comment: `keywordObject` is declared in the header `ObjectSet* keywordObject`.  It looks like not setting the `keywordObject` in the `else` was the problem.    `keywordObject = objectToKeywordMap.find(keyword)->second;`

Comment: @Phillip You need to put a return type for void functions as well. It would be a good idea to address the other points as well.

Answer (score 0):

most probably the problem is that you haven't define your sort function for the `key type` that that your map has. You need to 'tell' the map *how to sort the index-type*

For example:

```
struct sortKey{
bool operator()(key_type const& k1, key_type const& k2){
//define your sort criteria here
}

}
std::map<key_type,value_type,sortKey> the_map;
```

Please comment if you think there is something else that you are missing.

Comment: I don't have that implemented but maybe it is something I should do.

Comment: yes. otherwise you don;t know how the map will keep the values.